# trying to have user attend event via api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use Facebook's API code to have a user attend an event, but it's not working. I can run the post comment on my browser window but as a php script it's not working

```
$fields = array('access_token'=>$access_token);



$result = HTTP_POST("https://graph.facebook.com/4XXXXX663/invited?access_token=$access_token",// URL to query

       $fields,                 // POST fields; associative array
       USER_AGENT,                  // user-agent value
        "",                         // cookie storage and retrieval
        "",                         // proxy; type:ip:port[:user:pass]; supported types: http, socks5
        true,                       // return the data or not
        false,                      // include headers in the return data
        "",                         // set value for REFERER header
        true,                       // automatically follow "redirects" ("Location" header)
        false);                     // enable or disable multipart post (if uploading, set to true)
```

Comment: you might want to proper format your code

Comment: when you say 'not working', could you perhaps elaborate on that?

Comment: You should always try to minimize the number of assumptions that the answerer would have to make in order to answer your question. 'Not working' could mean : a) an exception is thrown b) nothing happens c)syntax errors d)some screwy runtime error... etc

Comment: by not working i mean the user does not attend the event. there is no other error

Comment: this works if i have the token beforehand, but i have to paste it in my address bar. I know that this is a post command, but it's not posting in php as a standalone script.

https://graph.facebook.com/eventID/attending?access_token=AAABnkD0iuagBAFYZBHfm9cPht5kma9jCnlorEZAX8Eg46Xnc0arqXCvP5WvDQj6K8Xo0hKbTVMcAVHTkC9ZALzpdhDKeOOQPg0TKgJyjARZAgZAu5yE1l&expires_in=4283&method=post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `access_token` with the URL as well as the POST data.

Remove the `?access_token=$access_token` part in your URL and try again.

Also it would be good if you could post the error you're getting, So we can see what's the actual issue and also make sure you post that `HTTP_POST` function so we can know if the cURL settings are correct (I'm assuming this function is using cURL).

**EDIT 1:** Removed, Just realized you're trying to attend an event and not invite.

**Edit 2:** You need to ask your users to give `rsvp_event` permissions in order to make them attend your event via your App. You also need to make an HTTP POST to `EVENT_ID/attending` (This is for attending the event) and not to `EVENT_ID/invited` (This is for inviting users/friends to your event).

Comment: I tried that. there is no error. upon completion the script redirects to a success page, which it does. But it simply refuses to want to attend this event. It does other things like wall posts OK. I imagine sending a curl post request to attend an event provided i already have the event ID is a fairly simple process requiring no more than 10 lines of code.

Comment: Have you given `rsvp_event` permission? That is needed to attend the event on behalf of the user via your App.

Comment: Also you need to make an HTTP POST to `EVENT_ID/attending` and not `EVENT_ID/invited`.

Comment: `var_dump($result);` and see what it says. Don't redirect to your landing page or w/e the next page is. See the results and post it here. It should either return `true` or `false` if not successful.

Comment: whoops . my coding wa correct for both attending and inviting friends. The mistake was that for my test event i wrongly assumed that facebook by default makes all event public when they are not. also i tried inviting friends to an event that was over.